# How to get the password in Windows Administrator

Tags: passwords, administrator

I was trying to install some applications in HP EliteBook 8460 and I failed to do it many times because it keeps on displaying or asking for the Administrator Password. I can't even use my internet connection in both local and wifi. Even if I will add another account, it will still ask for an Administrator password. Please help me on how to fix it.. I cannot do any actions anymore because of ADMINISTRATOR PASSWORD.

Comment: have you tried your account password?  Maybe you're an administrator.

Comment: Actually, this is not my PC and the owner gave me the password for the administrator but still it won't work. Is there any way on how to reset password. I mean, we want to remove the password in Administrator so that we could pursue our specific work inside the PC? thank you

Comment: You'd be stuck with something like this: http://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-reset-a-windows-vista-admin-password/